# combine box plots with triangle frame in R

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

I am trying to use R to show a merged boxplot, I am sure this could be easy, but the data I have is a little complicated, the data has triangle structure.

below it an example of the data frame **aa** and **dd**:

```
  2014-01-15 2014-02-15 2013-03-15 2013-04-15
1       0.34       0.23       0.33       0.24
2         NA       0.49       0.38       0.34
3         NA         NA       0.34       0.33
4         NA         NA         NA       0.28

  2014-01-15 2014-02-15 2013-03-15 2013-04-15
1       0.24       0.33       0.23       0.24
2         NA       0.29       0.28       0.44
3         NA         NA       0.34       0.31
4         NA         NA         NA       0.29
```

With the code below to generate the data.frame :)

```
aa <- data.frame(c(0.34,NA,NA,NA), 
+                   c(0.23,0.49,NA,NA),
+                  c(0.33,0.38,0.34,NA),
+                  c(0.24,0.34,0.33,0.28))

dd <- data.frame(c(0.24,NA,NA,NA), 
+                   c(0.33,0.29,NA,NA),
+                  c(0.23,0.28,0.34,NA),
+                  c(0.24,0.44,0.31,0.29))

colnames(aa) <- c("2014-01-15", "2014-02-15", "2013-03-15","2013-04-15")
colnames(dd) <- c("2014-01-15", "2014-02-15", "2013-03-15","2013-04-15")
```

I wrote the code to generate plot for each data-set,within the name as well.But it is weird that the plot can not show the axis.

```
boxplot(aa,names = c("2014-01-15", "2014-02-15","2013-03-15","2013-04-15"))
boxplot(dd,names = c("2014-01-15", "2014-02-15","2013-03-15","2013-04-15"))
```

How ever I tried to use the the code below the merge the plots:

```
boxplot(data.frame(aa,dd),names = c("2014-01-15", "2014-02-15","2013-03-15","2013-04-15"))
```

the graph looks like this, but without the date axis,i do not know why! And I want to put the data on same date together as well. But here, the data set is still separated :(

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues: you are plotting eight boxplots with four supplied names, which is why they don't show up. And as you say your data is still separated, this is because each column in the data gets plotted as it's own boxplot, in the sequence your data are in your column. The solution lies in another way of combining your data. I've used ggplot to create the plot, as it deals with grouped boxplots beautifully.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
#combine the data with a grouping variable, otherwise data is not identifiable
aa$group <- 'a'
dd$group <- 'd'

ad <- rbind(aa,dd)
```

Your data needs to be in a different format, with each observation on it's own line.

```
#melt the data
ad$id <- 1:nrow(ad)
ad_m <- melt(ad,id.vars=c("id","group"))
```

Plotting grouped bars:

```
p2 <- ggplot(ad_m, aes(x=variable, y=value,color=group))+
  geom_boxplot(position="dodge") 
p2
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, but actually, i still need eight bars(or boxes), but just put the boxes which are on same date as neighbors :( . Btw, I  ran the code you said in my studio, but the date could not show up again.

Comment: I have edited the answer, had misunderstood your sentence about 'combining dates'